# Wordpress navigation css

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm migrating my HTML / CSS website to WordPress (creating a theme). I'm using the code shown below to turn wordpress  'pages' into navigation li links.

The code works, But the Word press nav styling is slightly different to the HTML site.

The code should work the same in both cases, but I suspect WP is not applying either an **id** or **class**

Can anyone help me understand why these code snippets give different styling results (The same css sheet is used for both the wordpress and the non wordpress site)

WP nav code (found in header.php)

```
    <nav>
      <ul id="navigation" class="slimmenu"> 
        <?php wp_nav_menu(); ?>  
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

HTML site nav code

```
<nav>
  <ul id="navigation" class="slimmenu"> 
    <li><a href="bike-shed.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="mountain-bikes.php">Bikes</a></li>
    <li><a href="bicycle-parts.php">Parts</a></li>
    <li><a href="charity-bikeevents.php">Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact-bikeshed.php">Contacts</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You should not have wp_nav_menu() inside a `<ul>` element.

This function creates HTML which includes a wrapper (div) and it's own `<ul>` element. so your HTML is going to be invalid and your CSS is unlikely to work.

Just use:

```
<nav>
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu_id' => 'navigation', 'menu_class' => 'slimmenu') ); ?>  
</nav>
```

If your CSS selectors are not overly specific, they may still work with the HTML generated by WordPress.

Comment: Thank, you sir. I will try this, one question tho, can you also apply an id   <?php wp_nav_menu( 'id' => 'myid'); ?

Comment: i guess i need to alter the id and class of the containing element

Comment: I added menu_id, so that the <ul> element should have the same ID and class as in your original question.

Comment: thanks again , final question ...   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)    ... I seem to be getting this error.  Googling is throwing up many different answers... thanks again for your help on this

Comment: Oops. Forgot to put the array() in there. Fixed.